# How to pickup latest TFS build by CruiseControl

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, cruisecontrol.net, xcopy

I am using TSf2010 to build out asp.net project, which gets dropped to a drop folder.
I wish to use CruiseControl.net to xcopy the latest dropped folder to my cc working folder. 
Dropped folders are named such as PROJECT_20120301.1

Is there a way to tell cc which is the latest dropped folder from TFS? Or perhaps an XCOPY syntax to help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

you could sync up the build numbers with CC.net, however you could just use the xcopy or robocopy to do what your CC.net does